# Delete Row From Data Table

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to Delete the Multiple records from the DataTable 
For example :
in my case PaperId is Repeating several Times.I want to Delete it all Duplicate records.

i have written code but loop is giving error

```
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        sqlDad.Fill(ds);
        DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
        ds.Tables.Add(dt1);
        dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
        DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
        dt2 = dt1;
        List<DataRow> rowsToDelete = new List<DataRow>();

        foreach(DataRow dr in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
        {
            int r = ds.Tables[0].Columns.Count;
            string x =  dr.ItemArray[0].ToString();
            int counter = 0;
            foreach (DataRow dr1 in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
            {

                if (x == dr1.ItemArray[0].ToString())
                {
                    counter++;
                }
                if (counter > 1)
                {
                    rowsToDelete.Add(dr1);
                    foreach (DataRow row in rowsToDelete)
                    {
                        dt2.Rows.Remove(row);
                    }
                    dt2.AcceptChanges();
                    rowsToDelete.Clear();
                }

            }
```

Comment: Problem is this : Their is Multiple values in Table which can identified by Seeing the PaperId. I want to delete that Duplicate Record Just One Record Left of that Particular PaperId

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the [DefaultView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview_properties.aspx) of the DataTable and setting the sort order on the column that you don't want repeats to appear. You could loop over the rows and delete all the rows after the first one

```
// Work on the first table of the DataSet
DataTable dt1 = ds.Tables[0];
// No need to work if we have only 0 or 1 rows
if(dt1.Rows.Count <= 1) 
     return;

// Setting the sort order on the desidered column
dt1.DefaultView.Sort = dt1.Columns[0].ColumnName;

// Set an initial value ( I choose an empty string but you could set to something not possible here 
string x = string.Empty;    

// Loop over the row in sorted order
foreach(DataRowView dr in dt1.DefaultView)
{
    // If we have a new value, keep it else delete the row
    if(x != dr[0].ToString())
       x = dr[0].ToString();
    else
       dr.Row.Delete();

}
// Finale step, remove the deleted rows
dt1.AcceptChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try This

```
DataRow[] rows;
rows=dataTable.Select("UserName = 'ABC'"); // UserName is Column Name
foreach(DataRow r in rows)
r.Delete();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to remove the **entire row** from **DataTable** ,

try this

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();  //User DataTable
DataRow[] rows;
rows = dt.Select("UserName = 'KarthiK'");
foreach (DataRow row in rows)
     dt.Rows.Remove(row);
```